# Camel - move file only on an event

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Within Camel, what the best strategy to move a file when an external event occurs (e.g. someone calls a Spring controller handling method)? Looking at the documentation, the [File](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) Component only seems to allow for file monitoring or scheduled invocation but not event based invocation and only seems to be an input and not an output.

Ideally, something like;

```
//raise the event
Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(producerTemplate.getCamelContext());
producerTemplate.send("direct:move-file", exchange);
```

With the camel route looking something like;

```
//sample route logic
from("direct:move-file).to(<file move logic>);
```

Comment: Reading this [thread](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/File-consumer-event-based-not-polling-td5715349.html), it doesn't sound like your usecase is effortlessly supported, but I think you may get some ideas by reading that thread. In particular I like the idea of selectively starting and stopping the route.

Comment: @DavidS Thanks, i've seen this thread as well and this is one option (albeit overkill)/ i had hoped that in the 4 years since this thread, something new would be available within Camel that could facilitate this.

Comment: Can't you just move the file with java.io.File and its rename method? Just write a few lines of Java code to do that which you call on the event.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Yep;  Achieved in 2 lines when falling back to Java but this requirement is part of a bigger workflow so had hoped to keep consistency by using camel for the entire workflow and not "jump out" to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by not using the camel framework to move the file & simply falling back into standard java to move the file.